# Tensorflow: tf.assign does not assign anything

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a little tweaked version of the Batch Normalization operation; in which I need to keep the moving average values like mean and variance explicitly. In order to do that, I am doing some experimentation with assignment and control dependency mechanisms in the Tensorflow and I run into a mysterious problem. I have the following toy code; in which I am trying to test whether the `tf.control_dependencies` work as intended:

```py
dataset = MnistDataSet(validation_sample_count=10000, 
load_validation_from="validation_indices")
samples, labels, indices_list, one_hot_labels = 
dataset.get_next_batch(batch_size=GlobalConstants.BATCH_SIZE)
samples = np.expand_dims(samples, axis=3)

flat_data = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(GlobalConstants.TRAIN_DATA_TENSOR)
mean = tf.Variable(name="mean", initial_value=tf.constant(100.0, shape=[784], dtype=tf.float32),
               trainable=False, dtype=tf.float32)
a = tf.Variable(name="a", initial_value=5.0, trainable=False)
b = tf.Variable(name="b", initial_value=4.0, trainable=False)
c = tf.Variable(name="c", initial_value=0.0, trainable=False)
batch_mean, batch_var = tf.nn.moments(flat_data, [0])

b_op = tf.assign(b, a)
mean_op = tf.assign(mean, batch_mean)
with tf.control_dependencies([b_op, mean_op]):
    c = a + b

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

results = sess.run([c, mean], feed_dict={GlobalConstants.TRAIN_DATA_TENSOR: samples})
```

I am simply loading a data batch with each entry having 784 dimensions, calculate the moments of it and try to store the `batch_mean` into the variable `mean`. I trivially store the variable `a`'s value into `b` as well.

In the last line, when I run the graph for the values of `c` and `mean`, I see `c` as 10, which is the expected value. But `mean` is still a vector of 100's and does not contain the batch mean. It is like the `mean_op = tf.assign(mean, batch_mean)` has not been executed.

What can be the reason of this? As far as I know, all operations in the `tf.control_dependencies` call must be executed before any operation in the following context; I explicitly call `c` here, which is in the context. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known "feature"](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10860) of `tf.Session.run()`. The `c` and `mean` ops are independent, hence `mean` may be evaluated before `c` (which would update `mean`).

Here's a shorter version of this effect:

```
a = tf.Variable(name="a", initial_value=1.0, trainable=False)
b = tf.Variable(name="b", initial_value=0.0, trainable=False)
dependent_op = tf.assign(b, a * 3)
with tf.control_dependencies([dependent_op]):
  c = a + 1

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run([c, b]))
  print(sess.run([b]))
```

The second evaluation of `b` is guaranteed to return `[3.0]`. But the first `run` may return either `[2.0 3.0]` or `[2.0 0.0]`.

Comment: I did not completely understand. In my understanding, sess.run() has to run all the ops and their dependencies in the graph. I explicitly state c and mean in the sess.run(); why would it skip updating the variable "mean"?

Comment: Both ops are evaluated, but if the session evaluates `mean` **before** `c`, it will return the old value. You can verify that `mean` was updated by evaluating it again.

Comment: Ah ok, the graph fetches mean before it gets assigned the correct value. Then the same can happen to 'c', right?

Comment: Right, but in your example `c` will be `10`, no matter what the order is.

Comment: Why; if 'mean' can be fetched without the assignment, couldn't the same happen to 'c'; sess.run() fetches them with their initial values but the actual assignments do happen?

Comment: Both `c` and `mean` are evaluated. Evaluation of `c` respects `control_dependency`, hence the result is guaranteed to be 10. But it also has a side effect of updating the `mean`. And this is not guaranteed: `run` may evaluate `mean` first and then update it.